# Can't create dynamic objects using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to define a query object dynamically (which is used for some MongoDB method calling).

```
let query = {
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
}

if (isAdmin) {
  query = {
    category: { $exists: true },
    isFinalized: { $exists: false }
  }
} else if (isEditor) {
  query = {
    category: { $in: specialisation }
  }
}
```

It is only a small part of the object generation.
But with that I do get the TS error `Object literal may only specify known properties` for `isFinalized` and `category.$in`.

So how should I handle this correctly?

```
let query = {
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [], $in: undefined },
  isFinalized: undefined
}
```

This seems very ugly to me.

Comment: Does `query` have a type or is Typescript complaining about a random object?

Comment: Try to create union type and assign it to query

Comment: I guess you wouldn't want to define a type for `query` explicitly either in that case?

Comment: No. Query is not typed as it has very different structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a type with some optionals:

```
type Query = {
  category: {
    $exist?: boolean,
    $in?: any,
    $ne?: Array<string>,
  },
  isFinalized?: {
    $exists?: boolean;
  }
};

let query: Query = {
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
} as any;

if (isAdmin) {
  query = {... query,
    isFinalized: { $exists: false }
  };
} else if (isEditor) {
  query = { ...query,
    category: { $in: specialisation }
  }
}
```

---

Or the ugly one. Just use `as any`:

```
let query = {
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
}

if (isAdmin) {
  query = {
    category: { $exists: true },
    isFinalized: { $exists: false }
  } as any;
} else if (isEditor) {
  query = {
    category: { $in: specialisation }
  } as any;
}
```

In your code you create an element, then overwrite it directly (if or else). The first definition is useless. This way you prevent it:

```
let query;

if (isAdmin) {
  query = {
    category: { $exists: true },
    isFinalized: { $exists: false }
  }
} else if (isEditor) {
  query = {
    category: { $in: specialisation }
  }
}
```

Or:
You can use the spread operator to extend the object (if possible) and use `as any` on the first declaration:

```
let query = {
  category: { $exists: true, $ne: [] }
} as any;

if (isAdmin) {
  query = {... query,
    isFinalized: { $exists: false }
  };
} else if (isEditor) {
  query = { ...query,
    category: { $in: specialisation }
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the first definition as default value. In some cases this default object has to be modified or extended.

Comment: When you don't know all the possible parts, you have to use `any`. Think there is no way around.

Answer (score 1):

A Factory like class could be quite helpful when you separate roles out, allow different parts of the object to build separately based on the role and then put them together using 1 final public method:

```
enum Roles {
  Default = "Default",
  Admin = "Admin",
  Editor = "Editor"
}

interface ICategory {
  $exists?: boolean;
  $ne?: any[];
  $in?: string;
}

interface IIsFinalized {
  $exists: boolean;
}

interface IQuery {
  category: ICategory;
  isFinalized?: IIsFinalized;
}

class QueryBuiler {
  constructor(private role: Roles = Roles.Default) {}

  public getQuery(): IQuery {
    return {
      category: this.getCategory(),
      isFinalized: this.getIsFinalised()
    };
  }

  private getCategory(): ICategory {
    switch (this.role) {
      case Roles.Admin:
        return { $exists: true };
      case Roles.Editor:
        return { $in: "specialisation" };
      default:
        return { $exists: true, $ne: [] };
    }
  }

  private getIsFinalised(): IIsFinalized | undefined {
    if (this.role === Roles.Admin) {
      return { $exists: false };
    }
  }
}

console.log(new QueryBuiler(Roles.Admin).getQuery());
```

Comment: Answers with no explanation are rarely upvoted when there are answers with explanation...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Although it is a great solution ;-)

Comment: sorry but I thought the code was quite self explanatory. I can add some text

Comment: What if I need to remove a field? Assume there should not be a `category` field, if user is an admin, so there is no category in the result query...

Comment: make category optional too using ? and return it only when you like. Then in getCategory for case Roles.Admin return undefined and amend the return type to also have | undefined.